# On Open Script Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have attempted to create an on open script function for my google sheet. I would like the sheet to open to the current month tab when I open my document. However, my sheets are not labelled with just the month but also certain days to coincide with our payroll dates. Not sure how to correct my formula.

Here is the script I am using:

```
/**
 * Selects a monthly sheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var monthTabs = [ "Master", "Sick Summary", "Extra Hour Summary", "Sep15-
30", "Oct1-15", "Oct15-26", "Nov1-15", "Nov15-30", "Dec1-15",
    "Dec15-31", "Jan1-15", "Jan15-31", "Feb1-15", "Feb15-28", "Mar1-15", 
 "Mar15-31", "Apr1-15", "Apr15-30", "May1-15", "May15-31", "Jun1-15", 
 "Jun15-30" ];

  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(monthTabs[month]);
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
};
```

These are the labels of my tabs:

Master, Sick Summary, Extra Hour Summary, Sep15-30, Oct1-15, Oct15-26, Nov1-15, Nov15-30, Dec1-15, Dec15-31, Jan1-15, Jan15-31, Feb1-15, Feb15-28, Mar1-15, Mar15-31, Apr1-15, Apr15-30, May1-15, May15-31, Jun1-15, Jun15-30

I am wondering if I need to change the labels of my sheet or if I need to include the date specifications in my script?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your code like so:

```
function onOpen() {

  var monthConv = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
  var month = monthConv[(new Date()).getMonth()];
  Logger.log(month)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var MonthTabs = ss.getSheets()
  for(var i = 0; i< MonthTabs.length ; i++){
    var shtName = MonthTabs[i].getName()
    Logger.log(shtName.substr(0,3))
    if(shtName.substr(0,3) == month){
      Logger.log("Tab selected")
      if((new Date()).getDate()<15){
        ss.setActiveSheet(MonthTabs[i])
      } else {
        ss.setActiveSheet(MonthTabs[i+1])
      }
      break;
    }
  }

};
```

First, you will need to convert, the month to a three-letter code.

```
      var monthConv = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
      var month = monthConv[(new Date()).getMonth()];
```

Then you will need to extract the first three letter of the sheet name and compare it to the current three letter month code

```
        var shtName = MonthTabs[i].getName()
        Logger.log(shtName.substr(0,3))
        if(shtName.substr(0,3) == month){
```

Once a match is found, based on the current date you select the first sheet that matches or the sheet after it.

```
    if((new Date()).getDate()<15){
        ss.setActiveSheet(MonthTabs[i])
      } else {
        ss.setActiveSheet(MonthTabs[i+1])
      }
```

And this assumes the sheets are ordered based on months and dates. So it selects the next sheet if the current date is more than 15.

Hope that helps.